# Matching substring of pandas columns

Tags: pandas

Given table with code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({"item":['ABA','ADA','12AB','34CD','bCD','ABCD','d']})
```

and table

```
    item
0   ABA
1   ADA
2   12AB
3   34CD
4   bCD
5   ABCD
6   d
```

I want to replace string contains substring "AB" or "AD" as 1, "CD" as 2, matching start from beginning and we get the earliest match, e.g. 'ABCD' will be classied as 1.

Expected Output:

```
   item result
0   ABA      1
1   ADA      1
2  12AB      1
3  34CD      2
4   bCD      2
5  ABCD      1
6     d    NaN
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `str.extract`:

```
replace = {'AB':1, 'AD':1, 'CD':2}
pat = '|'.join(replace.keys())

df['result'] = df['item'].str.extract(f'({pat})', expand=False).map(replace)
```

Output:

```
   item  result
0   ABA     1.0
1   ADA     1.0
2  12AB     1.0
3  34CD     2.0
4   bCD     2.0
5  ABCD     1.0
6     d     NaN
```